# Does apple watch app need an iphone interface too?

Tags: iphone, app-store, apple-watch

When I want to upload my apple watch app to appstore , for example : currency converter which only uses watchkit extension and runs on watch. 
Do i need an iphone interface too to submit my app?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

You do definitely need an iPhone UI, Apple will reject it otherwise. As simple as that.

**Note**

As they announced, later this year developers may upload standalone-WatchApps but until then your iPhone app has to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to run Apple Watchkit app you need a paired Iphone , please go through the document

Apple Watch requires the presence of an iPhone to run third-party apps. To create a third-party app, you need two separate bundles: a WatchKit app (that runs on Apple Watch) and a WatchKit extension (that runs on the user’s iPhone). The WatchKit app contains only the storyboards and resource files associated with your app’s user interface. The WatchKit extension contains the code for managing the WatchKit app’s user interface and for responding to user interactions.

User interactions are what make the Apple Watch unique. First, you always provide users with a full-app experience, which they interact with by opening your app from the Home screen. The full interface, with its multiple screens of content, makes it easy for user to interact with your app’s data.

Besides the full-app experience, you can optionally offer users a read-only interface, known as a glance, which displays timely and relevant information from your app. Finally, you can change the way local and remote notifications are displayed to your users by providing custom notification interfaces.

Because a WatchKit app extends the behavior of your existing iOS app, the WatchKit app and WatchKit extension are bundled together and packaged inside your iOS app bundle. During installation of your iOS app, the system prompts the user to install the WatchKit app when a paired Apple Watch is present.

> WatchKit apps have two parts: A WatchKit extension that runs on iPhone
> and a set of user interface resources that are installed on Apple
> Watch. When your app is launched on Apple Watch, the WatchKit
> extension on iPhone runs in the background to update the user
> interface and respond to user interactions.
>
> i think you need an interface for the phone app , remember one thing never do any background heavy operations in watch kit app do all your heavy operations in watch kit extension that is running in your iPhone , and let the watchkit app and IPhone should communicate for data in between , and use watch kit app only for showing the user interface

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question. Does the phone app need an interface too or can it just be a blank single-view app template ?
I mean , if i like to make apps for apple watch, then don't want to make any iphone app, i only want to make the watch app. 

But at the moment there aren't native watch apps, so i need to use iphone ios app to run my watchki extension. But therse a catch, does this iphone app need an interface or i can just focus my apple watch extension ?